# why calling show() action is creating two separate jobs in the spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a simple query using spark Dataframe APIs and calling show() action on it.
I am seeing two jobs for this action and the second job has one skipped stage. from my understanding there should be a single job. **can anyone tell me reason for two jobs?**

**Query:**

```
Dataset<Row> result1 = df.where("runs > 12000").select("team", "run")
                        .groupby("team").agg(count("run").as(""total_run));

result.show();
```

**Job1:**
[image]

**Job2:**
[image]

Comment: @mike i have edited the question, I am applying show on the same dataframe